# result from Dsum is not adding when using a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get wrong answer on `DSum` using a variable. if I put a fix info, if it gets correct answer.

I If do like this works fine

```
xDefect = Nz(DSum("[defects]", "PO_Details", "Fornecedor = 'QMY'"), 0)
```

result QMY10

if I do with a variable

```
Dim xForner As Variant
Dim xDefect As Byte

xForner = Me.Fornecedor

xDefect = Nz(DSum("[defects]", "PO_Details", "Fornecedor = ' & xforner & '"), 0)
MsgBox "missing:" & xForner & xDefect
```

result QMY0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must concatenate the variable:

```
xDefect = Nz(DSum("[defects]", "PO_Details", "Fornecedor = '" & xforner & "'"), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug! Assign the string to a variable and look what it contains

```
Dim condition As String

condition =  "Fornecedor = ' & xforner & '"
MsgBox condition ' Or instead, set a breakpoint
xDefect = Nz(DSum("[defects]", "PO_Details", condition), 0)
```

Does `condition` really contain `"Fornecedor = 'QMY'"`?